# Помогите в unity3d у меня ошибка

Tags: unity3d

Не могу добавить компонент.

> Can't add script component 'PlayerController' because the script class
> cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that
> the file name and class name match.

Ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: Между юнити и проектом кода что-то не срослось. Перезапусти юнити и вижуал/моно.

Comment: Там же написано что ошибки в коде

Comment: Ошибка: выводится в консоль.
Консоль: Ошибок нет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь несколько вариантов причины ошибки:

1)
Вы создали скрипт, добавили его как компонент, но случайно удалили скрипт впоследствии (маловероятно, но все же)

2)
проверьте, объявили ли в самом скрипте класс. Если вы пишете на C#, то вот структура скрипта:

```cs
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class /*название скрипта */ : MonoBehaviour {

         void Start () {

        }
       
        void Update () {
        }
}
```

Comment: возможно он скопировал полностью другой скрипт и вставил в новый скрипт с другим названием и все полетело

Comment: возможно. в любом случае, в ответе указал **верную** структуру скрипта, где имя класса должно соответствовать файлу.

Answer (score 0):

название скрипта в ассетах и в коде проверь. Должно быть одно и тоже

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).